# Inline-buttons in Telegram bot stopped responding

Tags: python, aiogram

I faced this problem, Inline-buttons stopped responding, the reason is not clear. Here is a part of the code, maybe you can find the cause of the problem. I can't add more details, because the terminal doesn't show any errors

personal_action.py

```
BotDB = BotDB("Help_For_Tutors.db")
@dp.message_handler()
@with_subscription_check
async def text_cmd(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    match message.text:
        case "Weekly schedule":
            days = ["Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
            cal_days = ["Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
            buttons = []

            for i, day in enumerate(days):
                button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f"☑ {day}", callback_data=f"get_schedule:{cal_days[i]}")
                buttons.append(button)

            keyboard_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)
            keyboard_markup.add(*buttons)

            await message.answer("Pick the day you want:", reply_markup=keyboard_markup)

@dp.callback_query_handler()
async def callback(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    if call.data.startswith("get_schedule:"):
        cal_day = call.data.split(':')[1]

        days = ["Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
        buttons = []

        for i, day in enumerate(days):
            # Marking the selected day with a different icon
            if days[i] == cal_day:
                button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f"✅ {day}", callback_data=f"get_schedule:{days[i]}")
            else:
                button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f"☑ {day}", callback_data=f"get_schedule:{days[i]}")
            buttons.append(button)

        keyboard_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=4)
        keyboard_markup.add(*buttons)

        rows = await BotDB.get_schedule(call.message.chat.id, cal_day)
        status_icons = {
            'constant': '',
            'single': '',
            'trial': '',
        }
        students = []

        for row in rows:
            student = f"{status_icons.get(row[0], '')}Student {row[5]} {row[6]} \n" \
                      f"{status_icons.get(row[0], '')}⌛{row[1]} {row[2]} \n" \
                      f"{status_icons.get(row[0], '')}⌛Duration : {row[3]} min \n" \
                      f"{status_icons.get(row[0], '')}Price per lesson {row[4]} \n" \
                      "__________________________________________\n"
            students.append(student)

        if students:
            try:
                await call.message.edit_text(f"The schedule for {cal_day}:\n\n" + "\n".join(students),
                                             reply_markup=keyboard_markup)
            except MessageNotModified:
                pass
        else:
            try:
                await call.message.edit_text(f"Right now you don't have any lessons in {cal_day}",
                                             reply_markup=keyboard_markup)
            except MessageNotModified:
                pass
```

db.py

```
class BotDB:


    def __init__(self, db_name):
        self.db_name = db_name
        self.conn = None
        self.lock = asyncio.Lock()

    async def connect(self):
        async with self.lock:
            if not self.conn:
                self.conn = await aiosqlite.connect(self.db_name, isolation_level="EXCLUSIVE", timeout=30)
                self.cursor = await self.conn.cursor()
                print("Connection successfully open", datetime.datetime.now())

    async def close(self):
        async with self.lock:
            if self.conn:
                await self.conn.close()
                print("Connection successfully close", datetime.datetime.now())
                self.conn = None
    async def get_schedule(self, tutor_id, day):
        """Retrieve the schedule from the database for displaying it in the bot chat room"""
        today = datetime.datetime.now()
        start_of_week = today - datetime.timedelta(days=today.weekday())  # Start of the current week (Monday)
        end_of_week = start_of_week + datetime.timedelta(days=6)  # End of the current week (Sunday)

        await self.connect()
        schedule = await self.cursor.execute(f'SELECT sc.type_lesson, sc.lesson_day, sc.lesson_start, '
                                             f'sc.lesson_duration, s.price, s.student_name, '
                                             f's.student_surname, sc.student_id '
                                             'FROM Schedule sc '
                                             'INNER JOIN Students s '
                                             'ON sc.student_id = s.student_id '
                                             f'WHERE sc.tutor_id = {tutor_id} '
                                             f'AND sc.lesson_day = \'{day}\' '
                                             f'AND sc.date BETWEEN ? AND ? '
                                             f'ORDER BY lesson_start',
                                             (start_of_week.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), end_of_week.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
        result = await schedule.fetchall()
        await self.close()
        return result
```

No actions were taken on my part, as I cannot understand the cause of the malfunction